# Typeerror: news object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to fetch news from news api, i have set the function to return an array of the news results.am getting an error in my display template where i want to display the news.

```
def getNews():
  '''
  function that fetches all news
  '''

  with urllib.request.urlopen(news_url+'281dbdc2e10e4a6ab51a9a27a614c146') as me:
    news_data = me.read()
    news_response = json.loads(news_data)

    all_news = None

    if news_response['articles']:
      all_news_list = news_response['articles']
      all_news_data = process_news(all_news_list)

  return all_news

def process_news(news_list):

  all_news = []
  for news in news_list:
    author = news.get('author')
    title = news.get('title')
    description = news.get('description')
    url = news.get('url')
    urlToImage = news.get('urlToImage')
    publishedAt = news.get('publishedAt')

    if author:
      news_object = Article(author,title,description,url,urlToImage,publishedAt)
      all_news.append(news_object)

  return all_news
```

```
@main.route('/')
def index():
  news = getNews()
  title = "All News"
  return render_template('index.html',news=news,title=title)
```

```
{% for myNews in news %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @makozaki Given the code, `getNews` will always return `None`. `all_news` is never reassigned before it is returned.

Comment: You must understand that `all_news` is a **local** variable in both methods. You would have to return `all_news_data` from `getNews`, which is the actual output of `process_news`.